# How to uninstall Visual Studio 2010 Beta 1

Tags: visual-studio-2010, uninstallation

What are the steps necessary to properly uninstall VS 2010 Beta 1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd recomend the following post: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2001109
It works for me :)

Answer (score 1):

Didn't have any problem with uninstalling it. I just went to Add/Remove Program (or whatever it is in other version of windows) in the control panel and uninstalled the main one (Visual Studio 2010). this also removed all the other related installations.

Comment: It want an installation CD that I don't have anymore. It writes which file it want - I don't have it ... Strange that uninstall require install disc